# node-sass error when npm install with node version 18

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-sass

I upgraded the version of node to 18 and I am having these errors whit node-sass when I try to make npm i in my project, also I am having the same problem with react-app-rewire-sass-rule I can not updated it or installe it:
I am not looking for downgraded it, but fix theses errors.

any clue?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /home/valentinaga1/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/node /home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/valentinaga1/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.16.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.18
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 18.16.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '18.16.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "18.16.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 18.16.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 18.16.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:6771) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/valentinaga1/.node-gyp/18.16.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/valentinaga1/.node-gyp/18.16.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/valentinaga1/.node-gyp/18.16.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/valentinaga1/teamClass/teamClassPortal/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
```